# Counting Stochastic Processes and displaying relative value

Tags: plotting, manipulate, finance

Counting Stochastic Processes and displaying relative value

I have two watermarks and multiple stochastic processes given. I want both to display and count the stochastic processes which are below the two watermarks, namely watermark and watermark2:

Furthermore I also want do display the relative proportion af all processes below watermark and watermark2 to all processes.

In order to count the processes I used first generated a random matrix to get a little bit familiar with the counting fucntion the code is:

```
dataX = Table[RandomFunction[
        GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[0.1, 0.2, 10], {0, 10, 0.1}]["Path"], {3}]
```

Then:

```
processesX = Transpose[dataX[[#]]][[2]] & /@ Range@Length[assetsX]
```

Then I just wanted to count the process values beyond 20 by this code:

```
Count[Flatten[dataX], _?(# >= 20 &)]
```

this worked so I tried to apply it for my code, however, I have some problems and I am not sure if I have allpied it properly. I would be greateful for any help.

my code:

```
Manipulate[SeedRandom[seed]; meanvector := Mean[assets];
 assets = 
  Table[RandomFunction[
     GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[μ, σ, S0], {0, time, 
      0.1}]["Path"], {P}];
 processes = Transpose[assets[[#]]][[2]] & /@ Range@Length[assets];
 processesposition = 
  Flatten[Position[
    Min[processes[[#]]] & /@ 
     Range@Length[assets], _?(# > watermark &)]];
 processesposition2 = 
  Flatten[Position[
    Min[processes[[#]]] & /@ 
     Range@Length[assets], _?(# > watermark2 &)]];
 watermarkedassets = assets[[#]] & /@ processesposition;
 watermarkedassets2 = assets[[#]] & /@ processesposition2;
 watermarkedmeanvector = Mean[watermarkedassets];
 watermarkedmeanvector2 = Mean[watermarkedassets2];

 (*Counting Stochastig processes below watermark and watermark2*)
 StoProcbelowwatermark = 
  Count[Flatten[assets], _?(# >= watermarkedassets &)];
 StoProcbelowwatermark2 = 
  Count[Flatten[assets], _?(# >= watermarkedassets2 &)];
 (*Relative proportion of assetes belos watermark and watermark2 to \
all assets*)
 RelProportionwatermarktoall = StoProcbelowwatermark/P;
 RelProportionwatermark2toall = StoProcbelowwatermark2/P;

 (*Functions and Plotting*)
 G1 := ListLogPlot[assets, 
   GridLines -> {{}, {{watermark, 
       Directive[Green, Thick]}, {watermark2, 
       Directive[Orange, Thick]}}}, Joined -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> {"Time", "St"}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Style["Forecasted Stock Price\n (Brownian Motion)", Bold], 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thin, Lighter@Gray}]];
 G2 := ListLogPlot[{meanvector, watermarkedmeanvector, 
    watermarkedmeanvector2}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[{Thick, Darker@Red}], 
     Directive[{Thick, Darker@Blue}], Directive[{Thick, Black}]}];
 Show[G1, G2], {{S0, 100, "Initial Stock Value"}, 1, 500, 0.5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{μ, 0.08, "Drift μ"}, 0.01, 0.2, 
  0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},

 {{σ, 0.2, "Standard Deviation σ"}, 0.01, 1, 0.05, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{P, 6, "Paths"}, 1, 20, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{time, 10, "Time t"}, 1, 20, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{watermark, 75, "Watermark"}, 1, 500, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{watermark2, 70, "Watermark2"}, 1, 500, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{seed, 1, "New Random Case"}, 1, 100, 1},

 Button["Set Initial Values", {S0 = 100, μ = 0.08, σ = 
    0.20, P = 6, time = 10, watermark = 75, watermark2 = 70}, 
  ImageSize -> 150], 
 Dynamic["Mean watermarked processes = " <> 
   ToString[watermarkedmeanvector[[-1]][[2]]]], 
 Dynamic["Mean watermarked2 processes = " <> 
   ToString[watermarkedmeanvector2[[-1]][[2]]]],
 Dynamic["Mean of all processes = " <> 
   ToString[meanvector[[-1]][[2]]]],
 (*Displaying Processes below the two watermakrs*)
 Dynamic["Processes below watermark = " <> 
   ToString[StoProcbelowwatermark[[-1]][[2]]]],
 Dynamic["Processes below watermark2 = " <> 
   ToString[StoProcbelowwatermark2[[-1]][[2]]]],
 (*Displaying relative proportions Processes below watermakrs in \
relation to all processes*)
 Dynamic["relation processes below watermark and all processes= " <> 
   ToString[RelProportionwatermarktoall[[-1]][[2]]]],
 Dynamic["relation processes below watermark and all processes= " <> 
   ToString[RelProportionwatermark2toall[[-1]][[2]]]],
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Comment: Did you try `Length[processesposition]` and `Length[processesposition2]`?

Comment: For the proportions, just divide `Length[processesposition]` and `Length[processesposition2]` by `Length[assets]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the amount of processes below your watermarks you can use `Length[processesposition]` and `Length[processesposition2]`.

For the proportions, just divide `Length[processesposition]` and `Length[processesposition2]` by `Length[assets]`.

Comment: @ Rod Lm. thanks, i did it, but when I want do disply the results e.g. by adding Dynamic["assets below threshold = " <> 
   ToString[Length[processesposition][[-1]][[2]]]], 
 ControlPlacement -> Left] I get an error message

Comment: @MilanIvica You don't have to use `ToString[Length[processesposition][[-1]][[2]]]`... Just use `ToString[Length[processesposition]]`...

Comment: @ Rod Lm thanks. Now I get a result, but the numbers are updating continuously. e.g. all means, although I do not change the varialbes

Comment: @MilanIvica I think you've done some modifications in the original code, and this is somehow affecting the final result. Try to restart from the last code and put your new calculations.

Comment: @ Rod Lm thanks, do you accidently have 3-5 minutes to chat? I would like to ask you some stuff? thanks

Comment: thanks...waiting in the chat room from yesterday